# PHP : How to change dropdown list to Text ? [Checkout-Page WooCommerce]

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce on CheckOut-Page , the default of ['billing_state']shows in drop-down list which I want to change it to input[text]. The customer have to key-in the information by themselves.

please help,  thanks a lot

this code doesn't work for me. (after the customer key-in the state, it shows the state-code. It should show the state name that the customer-key-in)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 
'y_change_address_input_type', 10, 1 );

function y_change_address_input_type( $fields ) {
$fields['billing']['billing_state']['type'] = 'text';
return $fields;
}
```

Comment: The State field is a dynamic field, it's not always a dropdown, for some countries it becomes a simple text input, and for some countries, it shows the state/county dropdown list. So if you're trying to customize it then you'll have to check the deeper functions/codes where this dynamic validation for dropdown/text input type is being performed and there you can find a hook and apply your custom conditions there.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your comment, currently, I found the solution. I can switch from selection[option] to input[text] on hook `woocommerce_default_address_fields`, and the code work as I expected. (I don't know why the code will not work on `woocommerce_checkout_fields`. The code should have work on both `woocommerce_default_address_fields` and `woocommerce_checkout_fields`)

This is the work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'y_edit_state', 40, 1 );
function y_edit_state( $state_fields ) {
    $state_fields ['state'] = array(
        'label'       => 'stae', // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => 'stae', // Add custom field placeholder
        'required'    => true, // if field is required or not
        'class'       => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ),   // add class name
        'clear'       => false, // add clear or not
        'type'        => 'text', // add field type
        'priority'    => 80, // Priority sorting option

    );

    return $state_fields;
}
```